# Creating a tag cloud from text:nsp output

Tags: text, tag-cloud

I am using [Text::NSP](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-NSP/) which creates [n-gram](http://wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/N-gram) from text files. Is it possible to create tag clouds from an output file of Text-NSP? I have used and liked IBM Word Cloud Generator which only gives a tag cloud output from the frequency of each word within a file. However, I am working with 2-grams and 3-grams. In short, I need a tag cloud generator which will accept an input file with words and their occurrence number. I am running on Debian.
Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

I started to use [R snippets package](http://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/snippets/cloud.html) which is what I was searching for.
The output of text::nsp should be changed with some bash scripts in order to obtain a dataframe acceptable by the R.